# SQL Connection timeout not working as expected

Tags: sql, sql-server, timeout

I made following function to check whether connection is established or not.

Here I have made timeout = 15 seconds.

It works most of the time.

But sometime it throws exception before time.

So if I give same connectionstring, sometimes it works as per timeout and sometime it expires before time.

What is wrong with timeout?

```
Public Function IsDBExist(ByVal strConnectionString As String) As Boolean

        Try
            Using connection As New SqlConnection
                Dim str As New SqlConnectionStringBuilder(strConnectionString)
                str.ConnectTimeout = 15
                connection.ConnectionString = str.ToString()
                connection.Open()
            End Using
            Return True
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return False
        End Try

    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally it means the connection string provided allowed the client to reach an sql-server instance but then something went wrong. For example, database name specified doesn't exist or the user has no privileges to see it.

Comment: Nothing is being changed. :)

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: As I have manually changed connection string. I have changed connection string that has server name that doesnt exist. So error will come like "Network related or instance specific error..."

Comment: Does the  "Network related or instance specific error..." exception mention timeout as well or it's thrown before time?